# Embedding a Vimeo video in my Shopify site, but volume is muted-- how can I default the volume to being "on"?

Tags: video, shopify, vimeo, volume, mute

My site is relaxerie.com, and I'm currently trying set a Vimeo vid to autoplay with volume to welcome visitors to my site.  It autoplays, but the volume is off. The vid is only 15 seconds long so by the time the user turns the volume on, it's basically over.

I've inserted a section in my home page to call the video.  Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
<div class="section-hura-video">
  <video autoplay muted loop playsinline class="hurabg-video">
    <source 

src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0333/8806/9004/files/Relaxerie.com_Welcome.mp4?v=1604755437?re1=0&amp;autoplay=1">
  </video>
</div>

{% schema %}
{
"name": "Section name",
"settings": []
}
{% endschema %}

{% stylesheet %}
.section-hura-video{
  width:100%;
}
.hurabg-video{
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
{% endstylesheet %}

{% javascript %}
{% endjavascript %}
```

Comment: for most scenarios, modern browsers only support autoplay when muted

Comment: Thanks for the info. Any idea how I can embed it WITHOUT the autoplay turned-on then?  If I do this, will it default to the volume being unmuted?

Comment: Where is the vimeo link? I see Shopify link for the video.

Comment: To remove the autoplay, you should just need to remove the `autoplay=1` from the embed URL

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Your users must click something that triggers a "play" command on your video object.
   This could be a button or pop-up message (a welcome screen, subscribe/sign-up offer etc) where clicking some "OK" or "cancel" button runs a function that hides the pop-up and plays the video. The video will now auto-play with sound. PS: One website used scrolling (user clicked the scroll bar or at-least interacted with the page) to trigger sound in video auto-play.
2. Play the mute video while also playing the sound as separate file via an `<audio>` tag. since audio tags are allowed to autoplay. You might get A/V sync problems if the video stops to buffer but audio carries on playing. You can use media events to detect whenever the video tag is buffering/paused to also pause your audio tag.